# pt-online-schema-change error with big composite primary key

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key, percona, galera, pt-online-schema-change

I've a table with composite primary key with below structure:

CREATE TABLE `field_name_test` (
 `id_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `desc` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
 `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
 `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL ,
 `rev_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL ,
 `lang` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fname_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fname_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_type`,`type_id`,`rev_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`lang`),
  KEY `id_type` (`id_type`),
  KEY `desc` (`desc`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `rev_id` (`rev_id`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`),
  KEY `fname_format` (`fname_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

i'm running pt-o-s-c to change the collation of the table and it is working fine with other tables but this one is giving below error:

```
pt-online-schema-change --execute --password=#### --user=#### --socket=#### --port=#### --chunk-time=1 --recursion-method=none --no-drop-old-table --alter "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci , CHANGE desc desc varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci , CHANGE id_type id_type varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci , CHANGE lang lang varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci , ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC , LOCK=SHARED, ALGORITHM=COPY" D=db,t=field_name_test,h=localhost
```

No slaves found.  See --recursion-method if host ###### has slaves.
Not checking slave lag because no slaves were found and --check-slave-lag was not specified.
Operation, tries, wait:
  copy_rows, 10, 0.25
  create_triggers, 10, 1
  drop_triggers, 10, 1
  swap_tables, 10, 1
  update_foreign_keys, 10, 1
Altering `db`.`field_name_test`...
Creating new table...
Created new table db._field_name_test_new OK.
Altering new table...
Altered `db`.`_field_name_test_new` OK.
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Creating triggers...
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Created triggers OK.
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Copying approximately 3843064 rows...
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Dropping triggers...
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Dropped triggers OK.
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Dropping new table...
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Dropped new table OK.
`db`.`field_name_test` was not altered.
2017-09-15T09:18:47 Error copying rows from `db`.`field_name_test` to 
`db`.`_field_name_test_new`: 2017-09-15T09:18:47 Error copying rows at chunk 1 of db.field_name_test because MySQL used only 390 bytes of the PRIMARY index instead of 497.  See the --[no]check-plan documentation for more information.

I'm running above in Galera 3 node cluster.

So i've below concerns on pt-o-s-c:
1) what solutions can be for above such cases ?
2) Is it possible to run parallel pt-o-s-c in a same database ?

Please let me know if any other input you need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you doing it TOI or RSU?

Comment: There are short language codes; why not use them instead of spelling out long utf8mb4 strings.

Comment: Drop  the index on `deleted` while you are at it; low-cardinality indexes are rarely used.  `KEY(type_id)` is a prefix of another index, so it is virtually useless.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames for replying.
* I'm using TOI with pt-o-s-c method
* this requirement is for emoji support.
* your suggestion is right to delete indexes, as this is application data and i'm dba so i don't want to change any structure, i've 100's of similar kind of tables.